# sorting the characters based on user preferences in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a column in a table with values like below

```
col1
----
AGP
BBP
CGR
DER
ESP
```

While selecting need the values to be sorted like below

```
col1
---
DER
ESP
AGP
CGR
BBP
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT col1
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY
       CASE col1
       WHEN 'DER' THEN 1
       WHEN 'ESP' THEN 2
       WHEN 'AGP' THEN 3
       WHEN 'CGR' THEN 4
       WHEN 'BBP' THEN 5
                  ELSE 6
       END;
```

or `DECODE`:

```sql
SELECT col1
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY
       DECODE( col1, 'DER', 1, 'ESP', 2, 'AGP', 3, 'CGR', 4, 'BBP', 5, 6 );
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col1 ) AS
SELECT 'AGP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CGR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ESP' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> | COL1 |
> | :--- |
> | DER  |
> | ESP  |
> | AGP  |
> | CGR  |
> | BBP  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f6f4883e8e89c509aef944142dd3cbea)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DECODE` in the `order by` as follows:

```
select * 
  from your_table
order by decode(col1,'DER', 1, 'ESP', 2, 'AGP', 3,
                     'CGR', 4, 'BBP', 5, 6)
```